# How to allow the setting of the Views Exposed Filters one at a time, instead of showing all available exposed filters at once

Tags: views

I have a view with a ton of exposed filters. Placing all in one page (even in a collapsible fieldset) is overwhelming for the users. Is there a module that allows a users to add a filter one-by-one?

Hopefully the screenshot of a third party application helps to explain

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe the [views dependent filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_dependent_filters) module will do it for you.

I haven't used it but from what I can see it works just like dependent fields.